# viewport-fit=cover does not work on the iOS Safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, web, safari

I am trying to get my website to fill the screen (notch) left and right sides when in landscape mode on IOS Safari but NONE of the solutions work.

I have added the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">` and I have also added

```
@supports(padding:max(0px)) {
    body, header, footer {
        padding-left: min(0vmin, env(safe-area-inset-left));
        padding-right: min(0vmin, env(safe-area-inset-right));
    }
}
```

I have noticed that background color on the body tag does work but I have background images that need to fill the space.

Does anyone have any ideas or solutions?

UPDATE:

Here is a screen shot of what I am talking about
[image]

Here is the CSS

```
div.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_6 {
    background-position: center top;
    background-image: url(https://XXXXXX.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/graphic-pattern@2x.png),linear-gradient(180deg,#80b6d7 0%,#d2c5de 100%)!important;
}
```

Comment: Please show us how you are setting up the background image and telling it to fill the space. A runnable snippet would be particularly helpful to us for testing on real IOS devices. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I updated the question. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I need a runnable snippet in order to try it on iOS as SO doesn’t allow snippet creation on a touch device.

Comment: I have noticed two viewport meta tags and I am starting to wonder if this is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. It was the two meta tags named viewport conflicting with each other and it was eventually found in my parent theme. So I was able to replace the function from the child theme.

Comment: safari respects it, but chrome does not?

Answer (score 1):

`viewport-fit=cover` seems to work for me, but not when run as a snippet. You do not see the desired result when you run the snippet below on an iPhone. (I believe this is a limitation of snippets — even a snippet showing in full page is still within an `iframe`, so the scope of the meta tag is limited to that `iframe`.)

However, try [this link](https://donald.net.au/bugs/notch.html) which has effectively the same code as the snippet, and you can see that the image does fill around the notch area (when the phone is in landscape orientation).

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/1000);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100svh;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am still trying to figure out how to either override or remove the "viewport" meta tag that Wordpress automatically adds to I can then add my "viewport" meta tag with the viewport-fit=cover param

Comment: It’s probably hardcoded in your theme. Try editing header.php.

Comment: I’m using the Divi and could not find it.